# How to remove items from array that begin with "XXX"

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have the follow array:

```
var array = ["app_angrybirds", "app_flappybird", "ilovebirds"];
```

How would you go about removing any array element that begins with the string `"app_"`?

Comment: sounds like looping through it with regex would be the most straight forward approach

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Look into [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) / [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `startsWith` is ES6 therefore not yet available for every browsers

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i].substr(0, 4) === "app_") {
      array.splice(i, 1);
      i--;  //The index will be moved one forward at the end of the loop, but the whole array
            //will be shifted, so we compensate by decrementing i
   }
}
```

You can just loop through and check the first 4 characters (using substr) and compare it. If they match, remove the element using splice. We also use a small hack using i-- to keep the index pointing at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the above:

The for loop steps through each element of the array. For each iteration, you compare the first four characters of the element,whose index matches with the iteration variable, to the string "app_". Here the array method substr(0,4) isolates the characters from the 0th element up to but not including the 4th element and makes the substring available for comparison with "app_".If the condition is true that the substring of the element matches with "app_" , use the splice() method to surgically remove the element from the array based on the parameters you pass to it, in this case the ith element.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way that I can think of:

```js
var array  = ["app_angrybirds", "app_flappybird", "ilovebirds"];

var result = array.filter(doesNotHave(/^app_/));

alert(JSON.stringify(result));

function doesNotHave(regex) {
    return function (str) {
        return !regex.test(str);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.